# Download Dow Jones 30 shares (all the 30 shares) into R

Tags: r, download, finance

I'm trying to download data from yahoo finance of all the 30 shares that are components in Dow Jones index. I have tried also with the Toronto stock exchange(tsx) but no way, I receive the same message from R. Please someone can help me with the code and get at the same time all the shares. It won't great if I get all the 30(dow Jones 30) or Tsx(60 shares) hand by hand. These are my codes:

```
dow=read.csv("DowJones30.csv",header=TRUE)
```

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

In addition: Warning message:

> In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'DowJones30.csv': No such file
>   or directory

---

```
dow=read.csv("tsx.csv",header=TRUE)
```

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

In addition: Warning message:

> In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'tsx.csv': No such file or
>   directory

Answer (score 0):

That error means you don't have the file in your current working directory (`getwd()`).

If you're trying to get the DowJones30.csv file hosted at R-Forge, you can actually load it directly by URL:

```
df <- read.csv('http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/fBasics/data/DowJones30.csv?revision=1&root=rmetrics&pathrev=1',sep=';');
head(df);
##    X.Y..m..d   AA  AXP     T    BA  CAT    C   KO    DD    EK   XOM   GE    GM  HWP   HD  HON INTC   IBM    IP  JPM  JNJ  MCD   MRK MSFT   MMM    MO    PG  SBC  UTX  WMT  DIS
## 1 1990-12-31 5.92 4.70 14.67 21.77 9.30 1.87 9.88 13.15 23.02 12.09 4.63 19.72 3.91 2.80 5.70 1.20 27.86 20.45 2.67 7.31 7.08 11.83 2.08 31.41 10.55 20.91 9.75 9.31 7.05 7.86
## 2 1991-01-02 5.92 4.70 14.67 21.77 9.30 1.87 9.88 13.15 23.02 12.09 4.63 19.72 3.91 2.80 5.70 1.20 27.86 20.45 2.67 7.31 7.08 11.83 2.08 31.41 10.55 20.91 9.75 9.31 7.05 7.86
## 3 1991-01-03 5.88 4.73 14.73 21.71 9.15 1.87 9.60 12.83 22.95 12.15 4.53 19.57 3.91 2.74 5.67 1.20 27.95 20.21 2.67 7.23 6.99 11.45 2.09 30.90 10.27 20.70 9.64 9.19 7.05 7.82
## 4 1991-01-04 5.76 4.73 14.79 22.50 9.00 1.92 9.85 13.06 22.74 12.27 4.47 19.00 3.85 2.75 5.65 1.20 27.86 20.50 2.69 7.18 7.02 11.27 2.11 30.80 10.24 20.48 9.56 9.24 6.97 7.79
## 5 1991-01-07 5.72 4.58 14.67 21.65 8.87 1.89 9.69 12.83 22.11 12.12 4.40 18.35 3.88 2.65 5.50 1.19 27.39 20.45 2.58 6.96 6.80 10.97 2.08 30.43 10.08 20.05 9.40 8.95 6.82 7.58
## 6 1991-01-08 5.63 4.53 14.73 21.34 9.05 1.85 9.60 12.60 22.18 12.09 4.44 18.28 3.90 2.59 5.47 1.18 27.08 20.26 2.58 7.02 6.83 11.01 2.04 29.65 10.11 20.02 9.32 8.78 6.85 7.41
```

Comment: df <- read.csv('http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/fBasics/data/Tsx60.csv?revision=1&root=rmetrics&pathrev=1',sep=';');
head(df)                                                                                                                                                  I have tried with this code to get the toronto stock exchanges shares but no way i'm not getting the 60 stocks i need for my analysis. How is it  possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a tsx60.csv file anywhere, I'm not aware of one.

Answer (score 0):

Another way! Just for the record.

```
library(XML) 
urlt <- "http://money.cnn.com/data/dow30/" 
doc.html = htmlTreeParse(urlt, useInternal = TRUE)
tables <- readHTMLTable(doc.html,as.data.frame=FALSE)
length(tables)
tables[[2]]
tables <- readHTMLTable(doc.html,
                        stringsAsFactors=FALSE,which = 2)

ticker=sapply(1:length(tables$Company),function(xs)
  strsplit(rawToChar(charToRaw(text[xs])),"Â",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][1]
  )
#ticker <- as.vector(as.character(ticker))
library(quantmod)
StockData <- new.env()
data <- getSymbols(ticker, env = StockData)
do.call(merge, eapply(StockData, Cl)[ticker])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in R-Studio, select 'Session' from the dropdown menu at the top of the screen, then 'Set Working Directory > Choose Directory', and select the folder which contains the file you are want to open (in this case "DowJones30.csv" & "tsx.csv").

If you are not working in R-Studio I highly recommend that you install R-Studio.